# Who are some ancient Singers of Sanskrit in the past?

Tags: history, culture, sanskrit

Sanskrit is a phonetically active language that vibrates brain and heart and makes the environment positive. Could you suggest a few Sanskrit singers of ancient India whom one may listen to?
Thanks!

Comment: Ravana. He composed Shiva Tandava Stotram.

Comment: many of MS subbulakshmi's songs